# js forEach() to perform action on each element

Tags: javascript

I have the follwoing:

```
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton = function(inputs) {
    inputs.forEach(function(argument){
        argument.parent().removeClass(HB.formButtons.SUBMIT_BUTTON_STYLE);
    });
}
```

which I than call in various parts like so:

```
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton($(HB.personalDetails.SUBMIT_PERSONAL_DETAILS_SELECTOR), $(HB.personalDetails.CANCEL_PERSONAL_DETAILS_SELECTOR));
```

The console. throws the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: formsInput.forEach is not a function

Why?

Comment: maybe because `inputs` is a jQuery object and not an Array ? (you are passing multiple parameters to `deactivatingButton ` , not an array)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `input` to be `HTMLCollection`, the `forEach` doesn't work on a collection. `forEach` works on `Array`

You can, however, make it work like

```
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton = function(inputs) {
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function(argument){
        argument.parent().removeClass(HB.formButtons.SUBMIT_BUTTON_STYLE);
    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery object is an `HTMLCollection` ?

Comment: [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) has `item()` method while jQuery object has not ...

Comment: The `jQuery` object, is a collection of HTMLCollection objects. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to pass your function array of two elements you have to use square brackets `[]`.

```
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton(
[
    $(HB.personalDetails.SUBMIT_PERSONAL_DETAILS_SELECTOR),
    $(HB.personalDetails.CANCEL_PERSONAL_DETAILS_SELECTOR)
]);
```

alternative you can use the special variable `arguments` in your function. Described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments